# How to programmatically remove the digital signature from VBA macros in Excel?

Tags: excel, digital-signature, vba

Is there any way to programmatically remove the digital signature from the VBA macros of an Excel sheet?

i.e. code that is equivalent to entering the VBA editor, going to Tools menu -> Digital Signature and clicking Remove.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.
It's deliberately not part of the Excel object model for security reasons.

It is possible to remove the certificate from the certificate store. This requires Win32 api calls (which can be made from VB6 or VBA but I'm not sure of the exact effect on your project once you do this...
It will definately invalidate the certificate, but I don't know if it will remove it.
Also you may not wish to remove the certificate from the store (since you could be using it for something else).

To view the certificate store, type, **certmgr.msc** at the Run prompt.

anyway a link on how to remove a certificate programmatically.
[KB article showing how to remove a trusted root certificate from the store.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555894)

Requirements:
1. You'll need to download the Windows SDK for the appropriate platform to get the capicom dll's, + regsvr32 them
2. You'll need to extract the public key from the certifcate you want to remove.
3. Test with a uninmportant workbook first, I have no idea whether this method will (apart from invalidating the certificate) also cause corruption in the workbook. Hopefully someone has a better suggestion than this.

Comment: +1 good answer! however, the OP is no longer on SO (as indicated by being greyed out and no points), so they'll never be able to checkmark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @Otaku, that's cool. My main focus on SO atm is on answering interesting Office and VBA questions. as you can see by my low rep, I am probably not working the rep angle enough, oh well not to worry. Hopefully someone in the future will benefit from such an answer. I have got alot from SO - time to give back!

Comment: The OPs question wasn't about removing a certificate but removing a digital signature from the excel file (although created by a certificate with private key, the signature is not the same thing and removing the cert from your cert store will not invalidate the signature)

Comment: @Marwie huh? I clearly stated in my answer that there is NO WAY you can do the programmatic version of Digital Certificate > Remove method through the UI of VBA IDE. The proposed method removes the underlying certificate so if its machine based that will invalidate the files certificate.

Comment: You're making some very clear assumptions without stating them: Removing a CAs cert from the store is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut - you will kill the trust to any other cert signed with this CA. Although this might be a feasible way in very known environments with self signed certs it is most often a very bad idea to remove a CA or even public trusted CA to kill trust to a single signature as this will kill also the possibilty to securely use that machine for other things like tls. I think this should be clearely stated and differentiated in the extended answer.

Comment: Your making some correspondingly false assumptions about the usage and nature of code signing certificates. These are not the same as webserver certificates - used for "things like tls". As you say if you know the environment and the certificate then it is hardly a sledgehammer approach. Also I don't think its a "sledgehammer" type approach if its actually the only approach that works.