# Is there a way to programmatically add a digital signature to a VBA Macro in a word document?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, interop, ms-office

Is there a way to programmatically add a digital signature to a VBA Macro in a word document using C# or VB.Net?

There are some similar questions asked already; however, none that I could find answer my question: 
[How to programmatically remove the digital signature from VBA macros in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201195/how-to-programmatically-remove-the-digital-signature-from-vba-macros-in-excel)
[Digital Signature for Excel Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373176/digital-signature-for-excel-macro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't an automation API for this in the VBA environment. I got it working 100% unattended (so I could use it in automated builds) by P/Invoking Win32 APIs to grab the right window handles and simulate the keyboard shortcuts to those windows, highlight the right cert, etc. Even had it working to detect and capture compilation errors (grab the error dialog window and dig out the label control text). It took me a few days of hacking to get it working reliably, but it is possible, and really not even that hard.

I'd be happy to post it, but my previous employer owns the code. :(

Comment: massive hack job! probably good idea you didn't share - only thing its going to teach is how to hack windows. ** btw full respect - the solution you describe would have been very difficult to pull off.